# ip register/login system, security errors, masked IP address

Tags: php, authentication, ip

Is it possible in php to make a IP register/login system?

**Scenario:**

A user visits my site and it is checked if his/her IP exists in the database.

If the IP does not exist, then the IP is added as a new user. If the IP exists, then the user is logged in.

I know the code to get the IP address of the visitor. However, I do not know if this causes any major security considerations.

Can masked IP addresses be real IP addresses taken up by other people, or are they completely unique as well?

Comment: Well the first problem (of many) I can see is that IP addresses can change. Overall it's a bad idea.

Comment: No security on a ip-adress is a bad idea .... and it will not work at all ips can change the adress by every request (aol t-online was named in this scenario) ... proxys of mask the "ip-adresss" and all users behind have the same to your server .. all in all let it

Comment: some umts providers use NATTING, so all customers have the same ip adress :-)

Comment: You should try making use of PHP sessions instead of storing the IP address. There are times when multiple users may visit you from the same LAN, which is likely to figure as a single IP, if the LAN has only one exit router.

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses are a data delivery mechanism. They are **not**:

- guaranteed to be unique
- guaranteed to be stable (i.e. they'll change)
- unique per machine or user
- meant to be authentication mechanisms

So no, an IP is not a good data point to use for user identification. For starters, it doesn't give the user the ability to use his account from a different location/machine, and it means all users with the same IP (yes, this is perfectly common) share one account.

Answer (score 0):

IPs can be changed with proxies, and many people can be behind the same IP in a NATTed network, such as an office or a home network. Also, most IPs are dynamically assigned, so reconnecting will change the IP address.